# VCAP_SERVICES return null

Tags: jakarta-ee, environment-variables, ibm-cloud

I have the next code to connect my app to a DB2 database:

```
public static Connection init() {
    String VCAP_SERVICES = System.getenv("VCAP_SERVICES");
    Connection con = null;
    if (VCAP_SERVICES != null) {
        JSONObject vcap;
        try {
            vcap = (JSONObject) JSON.parse(VCAP_SERVICES);
            if(vcap.get("sqldb") != null) {                 
                con = initSQLDataBase();
            }
        } catch(IOException ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }   
    }
    return con;
}
```

My problem is that it never do the *if* because *System.getenv("VCAP_SERVICES")* returns always null.

The VCAP_SERVICES exists in Bluemix and I can connect my database in the Database Development Plugin for Eclipse, so I don't know what is wrong in my code.

Can someone helps me?

Thank you very much and sorry by my poor English.

[EDIT]: The problem is solved. It was by a problem elsewhere in the code. Sorry.

Comment: Can you confirm your application is running on Bluemix? That environment variable won't exist when you are running the application locally in Eclipse.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, doesn't look like you have a key defined to obtain SQLDB.  There's a very detailed code snippet at the link below that shows you how to parse vcap services:

https://www.ng.bluemix.net/docs/services/SQLDB/index.html#parse-vcap-in-java

Comment: Thank you for the answer, but my problem is that System.getevn("VCAP_SERVICES") return null, not the parse. It's like the app was not blinded with de database, but in bluemix it appears blinded.

Comment: Try adding something like this to ensure the contents of VCAP_SERVICES:

`writer.println("VCAP_SERVICES content: " + VCAP_SERVICES);